# I need a ducted vent hood over my gas range and microwave., t would like to leave my over the range microwave. Can the hood work right this way?

Tags: exhaust, range-hood

30" LG gas oven;  30" Kitchen Aid  microwave.  Able to vent the hood through the attic to the outside.

Comment: Generally microwaves dont need them due to the short time ghey are on. We have an exhaust mounted in the celing for it with a humidity sensor. It nevef triggers because of cooking, only during humid days. But you can always get a custom one made. Please post a photo of them in it.

Comment: We have no idea what's in your attic.  To tell if this is viable.  If you need to know if your microwave can be vented outside, the answer is maybe.   Most microwaves have an option to vent outside.  Some require a change of a plate. Some require the turning of the fan itself.  If you still have the instruction booklet for the micro, refer to that.

Comment: AFIK you cannot have a microwave oven over a cooktop which is used for serious cooking. You need an unobstructed hood that vents to the outside. Certaianly not with a gas cooktop.

Comment: I assume the OP is concerned with venting cooking fumes and exhaust fumes from the gas cooktop, not fumes generated by cooking inside the microwave oven. OP is this correct?

Comment: A very high end hood might be available to vent a gas cooktop around a microwave oven. It would cost thousands to install and operate. Ask yourself, "Would Nigella Lawson have a microwave oven over her gas cooktop?"

Comment: Unclear what you're talking about here.  Physically, it would be a kludge.  You need about 24" of space between your cooktop and hood.  A standard countertop is 36" high.  The bottom of your hood would need to be at 60" or higher.  If you put a microwave above that, the bottom of your microwave is probably at 68" even if you use a back vent hood.  Is your family peopled by giants?  Does your microwave provide insufficient venting (or none)?

Comment: A gas cooktop generates a massive amount of waste heat when serious cooking is being done. Can a microwave oven be placed over a gas cooktop?